# Android Studio - Llenar un Recycler View desde SQLite DB cuando ingreso una palabra en EditText y toco Boton

Tags: android, sqlite, recyclerview, edittext

Estoy tratando de cargar la información de mi SQLite DB a mi Recycler View, cuando ingreso una palabra en el EditText y presiono el Boton "Mostrar", pero por alguna razon cuando toco el boton, no pasa nada, tampoco da ningún error ni nada en el log

Mi activity Verbos2:

```
public class Verbos2 extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Item> listaItem;
RecyclerView recyclerViewItem;
EditText etVerbos;
Button mostrar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.verbos2);

    etVerbos = findViewById(R.id.etIngresar);
    mostrar = findViewById(R.id.bnMostrar);

    listaItem = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerViewItem = findViewById(R.id.rvListItems);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerViewItem.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recyclerViewItem.setHasFixedSize(true);

    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(listaItem);
    recyclerViewItem.setAdapter(adapter);

    //   recyclerViewItem.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    mostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BaseDeDatos admin = new BaseDeDatos(getApplicationContext(), "verbos.db", getApplicationContext(), 10);
            SQLiteDatabase db = admin.getReadableDatabase();
            String[] parametros = {etVerbos.getText().toString()};
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from verbos WHERE verbos =?", parametros);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Item item = new Item();
                item.setVerbo(cursor.getString(1));
                item.setReferencia(cursor.getString(2));
                item.setEu(cursor.getString(3));

                listaItem.add(item);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Mi Recycler View:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
private ArrayList<Item> listItem ;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Item> listItem) {
    this.listItem = listItem;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View contentView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista, parent, false);
    System.out.println("CREATE VIEW HOLDER: " + viewType);
    return new Holder(contentView);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = listItem.get(position);
    Holder Holder = (Holder) holder;
    Holder.tvVerbo.setText(item.getVerbo());
    Holder.tvReferencia.setText(item.getReferencia());
    Holder.tvEu.setText(item.getEu());

    System.out.println("BIND VIEW HOLDER: " + position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItem.size();
}

public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView tvVerbo;
    TextView tvReferencia;
    TextView tvEu;


    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvVerbo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLista1);
        tvReferencia = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLista2);
        tvEu = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLista3);
    }
}
}
```

Mi SQLite Database:

```
public class BaseDeDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public BaseDeDatos(Context context, String s, Context applicationContext, int i) {
    super(context, "verbos.db", null, 10);
}

@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table verbos(id integer, verbos text, referencia text, eu text, voce text, nos text)");
        db.execSQL("insert into verbos values(1, 'agito', 'abalo', 'abala', 'abalamos', 'abalam')," +
                "(1, 'agito', 'abalava', 'abalava', 'abalávamos', 'abalavam')," +
                "(1, 'agito', 'abalei', 'abalou', 'abalamos', 'abalaram')");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS verbos");
        db.execSQL("create table verbos(id integer, verbos text, referencia text, eu text, voce text, nos text)");
        db.execSQL("insert into verbos values(1, 'agito', 'abalo', 'abala', 'abalamos', 'abalam')," +
                "(1, 'agito', 'abalava', 'abalava', 'abalávamos', 'abalavam')," +
                "(1, 'agito', 'abalei', 'abalou', 'abalamos', 'abalaram')");
    }
}
```

Y esta es la foto del layout donde ingreso una palabra en el EditText y luego toco el Boton "Mostrar", y abajo se puede ver el Recycler View en forma de lista, donde debería mostrarme los registros de mi SQLite DB, pero no lo hace:

[image]

Apreciaré cualquier ayuda!

Comment: Hola, Muestra algún error el LogCat?

Comment: Hola, no el Logcat no muestra ningún error. Traté bastante de modificar algo en el Activity Verbos2 donde hago la llamada a la DB pero no pude lograrlo, y así como lo ven no funciona.

Comment: Que palabra defines como verbo en el editText

Comment: yo le paso "agito" que si miras en la Base de Datos, está en los 3 registros, porque la idea es que al ingresar esa palabra, me muestre la información de los 3 registros en el Recycler View

Comment: Te puedo pedir una prueba?, elimina la aplicación completamente y vuelve a subirla a tu dispositivo, entonces prueba nuevamente, dime que sucede. @RodrigoPaz

Comment: Lo solucioné encarandolo de otra manera en la activity "Verbo2". Edito la publi para que veas como quedó.

Comment: Es mejor que si has encontrado una solución, lo pongas como una respuesta a tu pregunta, aunque seas tú mismo, en vez de editando la pregunta. Me ha tocado revisar tu clase y encontrar el problema para darme cuenta de que debajo estaba tu propia solución, cuando parecía que se trataba de otra clase distinta y no la corrección de la misma. En definitiva, me has hecho perder mi tiempo para darme cuenta de que tú mismo habías encontrado la solución. Si al entrar veo que ya hay una respuesta, no habría perdido ni un minuto. Edita esto y ponlo como respuesta.

Comment: Disculpa por el incidente, de haberlo sabido lo hubiera puesto como respuesta de primera. Te agradezco por tu ayuda y tu tiempo. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Lo solucioné encarandolo de otra manera en la activity "Verbo2". Así quedó la activity "Verbos2" funcionando correctamente:

```
public class Verbos2 extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerViewItem;
RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewVerbos;
EditText etVerbos;
Button mostrar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.verbos2);

etVerbos = findViewById(R.id.etIngresar);
mostrar = findViewById(R.id.bnMostrar);

recyclerViewItem = findViewById(R.id.rvListItems);
LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerViewItem.setLayoutManager(manager);

mostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        List<Items> completeList = new ArrayList<>();
        completeList.addAll(mostrarVerbos());
        recyclerViewVerbos = new RecyclerViewAdapter((ArrayList<Items>) completeList);
        recyclerViewItem.setAdapter(recyclerViewVerbos);
    }
});
}

public List<Items> mostrarVerbos(){
BaseDeDatos admin = new BaseDeDatos(getApplicationContext(), "verbos.db", 
getApplicationContext(), 10);
SQLiteDatabase db = admin.getReadableDatabase();
String[] parametros = {etVerbos.getText().toString()};
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM verbos WHERE verbos =?", parametros);
List<Items> verbos= new ArrayList<>();
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    do {
        verbos.add(new Items(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), 
cursor.getString(3)));
    }while (cursor.moveToNext());
}else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El verbo no existe", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
return verbos;
}
}
```